# Detecting key words across multiple columns and flagging them each in new columns

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have this type of data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 5),
  v2 = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 5),
  v3 = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 5),
  v4 = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 5)      
)
```

as well as a number of `key` words:

```
keys <- c("A", "C", "F", "H")
```

I want to (i) detect which `key`word is present in each column of `df` and (ii) create new columns for each of the `key`s, recording with `1`if that `key` is present. I've been using a `for` loop so far, which, however, does not work:

```
library(stringr)
for(i in keys){
  df[i] <- +str_detect(apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " "), keys[i])
}
df
  v1 v2 v3 v4  A  C  F  H
1  C  A  J  I NA NA NA NA
2  H  E  E  C NA NA NA NA
3  D  H  F  A NA NA NA NA
4  G  D  I  J NA NA NA NA
5  F  C  A  F NA NA NA NA
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, as the same logic applied to a single `key` does work:

```
+str_detect(apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " "), keys[1])
[1] 1 0 1 0 1
```

I'd be grateful for advice on how the `for` loop must be tweaked but also for an entirely different solution to the problem (e.g., `dplyr`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your for loop you are indexing on both the index and the name. Test `keys["A"]`, it'll return `NA`. You can use `which` to avoid this:

```r
library(stringr)
for(i in keys){
  df[i] <- ifelse(str_detect(apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " "), keys[which(keys == i)]), 1, 0)
}
```

output

```r
  v1 v2 v3 v4 A C F H
1  C  E  J  I 0 1 0 0
2  J  D  E  J 0 0 0 0
3  B  F  C  E 0 1 1 0
4  H  H  H  C 0 1 0 1
5  F  A  A  B 1 0 1 0
```

Another option would be to index on the position (1, 2, 3, 4):

```r
for(i in seq_along(keys)){
  df[keys[i]] <- ifelse(str_detect(apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " "), keys[i]), 1, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `base` solution:

```r
cbind(df, +sapply(keys, grepl, x = do.call(paste, df)))

#   v1 v2 v3 v4 A C F H
# 1  C  E  J  I 0 1 0 0
# 2  J  D  E  J 0 0 0 0
# 3  B  F  C  E 0 1 1 0
# 4  H  H  H  C 0 1 0 1
# 5  F  A  A  B 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`'s `if_any`:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
bind_cols(df,
          map_dfc(keys, \(x) df %>% 
                    transmute(!!(x) := +(if_any(v1:v4, \(y) str_detect(x, y))))))
```

output

```r
  v1 v2 v3 v4 A C F H
1  C  E  J  I 0 1 0 0
2  J  D  E  J 0 0 0 0
3  B  F  C  E 0 1 1 0
4  H  H  H  C 0 1 0 1
5  F  A  A  B 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: Nice but how can the new columns be named correctly, i.e., `A, C, F, H`?

Comment: I'm trying to solve this but so far I'm not sure how to handle that.

Comment: Found it! See edit

Comment: Cool .. but a bit complicated ;), upvoted anyway!

Comment: Very much so ahah. I'm hoping besides @Darren's elegant base R solution, tidyverse has a better option to offer :)

Comment: Another form of your code: `df %>% mutate(a = map_dfc(set_names(keys), ~ +if_any(v1:v4, str_detect, .x))) %>% unpack(a)`